# KnitR unable to download documents

Tags: r, knitr

I am able to run this code normally in R.

```
setInternet2(use = TRUE)
download.file("http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/dsscapstone/dataset/Coursera-SwiftKey.zip", "Coursera-SwiftKey.zip", method = "curl", mode = 'wb')
unzip("Coursera-SwiftKey.zip", files=c("final/en_US/en_US.twitter.txt", "final/en_US/en_US.news.txt", "final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt"), exdir=".")
```

But when i try to use knitR it gives me this error

```
Quitting from lines 15-21 (milestone.Rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:5:106: unexpected ')'
4: unzip("Coursera-SwiftKey.zip", files=c("final/en_US/en_US.twitter.txt", "final/en_US/en_US.news.txt", "final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt"), exdir=".")
5: file.copy(c("final/en_US/en_US.twitter.txt", "final/en_US/en_US.news.txt", "final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt"?)
                                                                                                            ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse
Execution halted
```

I am using R Studio and MAC OS X.

I tried removing the s from https but it still di not work.

Comment: Would you please post a (minimal version of) `milestone.Rmd`?

Comment: Your code is simply syntactically incorrect. Without a minimal reproducible example, I don't think anybody can help you.